# GIF is not being displayed in Edge and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, gif

I included a kind of a loading panel in an application. It looks like this:

Here is my JS code. It generates the loadingElement and appends it to the body.

```
function addLoadingLayer() {
    var loadingElement = 
    '<div class="containerLoading"><div class="layerLoading"></div></div>';
    $("body").append(loadingElement);
}
```

Here are my two CSS classes that style the loadingPanel.

```
.containerLoading {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.layerLoading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    background-image: url('/img/hourglass.gif');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;     
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    border: 3px solid #007DC1;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

In the application I'll call the JS function like this to display the animation:

```
<select name="selectItem" onchange="addLoadingLayer(); submit();">
```

If the selected item is being changed the JS function will be called. To hide the loading panel, the JS function submit() is called.

Everything is working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Edge or IE. What is wrong? Any good ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: P.S: in IE there is just an empty square (where in the other browsers the gif is placed). And in edge I just see a full-screen white background for a moment.

Comment: If you navigate directly to <yoursitelocation>/img/hourglass.gif in Edge, can you see the .GIF image? If you provide a link to the GIF here, it would aid in testing. Maybe there's something about your image that just isn't supported by IE's GIF rendering engine

Comment: Knowing more about your image might help. Everything seems to be working when I link to a placeholder image in [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d4sn4whd/). Is your GIF actually a GIF? I've seen instances where a client/developer has changed the file extension of an file thinking that that alone will simply convert it to the requested file type, i.e. `file.pdf` => `file.jpeg`. Then, when linked to in the browser doesn't work across the board.

Comment: @SactoJosh: yes. If i navigate directly to the gif image, i can see the gif in all browsers.

Comment: @hungerstar: yes, it is a gif image. I created it online but I don't know the site now. And if I navigate directly in the browser to the image I can see it including the animation.

Comment: @hungerstar 's JSFiddle doesn't duplicate your code exactly but I like the idea of the placeholder GIF. Here's your code exactly with a placeholder GIF: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1db8wz9/11/) It works just fine in IE. Double check your GIF url maybe? I did remove the "submit()" from your onchange since we don't have the form code there but everything else is working fine...

Comment: .@SactoJosh: yes. i've found out that without the submit() the gif works fine in every browser. But I need to call the submit (a pre-defined JS function) to 'finish' the animation after it is completed.

Comment: I think I found a solution. I just put a '<img src="/img/hourglass.gif"' />' into the <div class="containerLoading"><div class="layerLoading"></div></div>'. But the gif image should have a white background. Then I have two solutions that work for IE, Edge, Chrome, and FF.

Comment: @Wacki if  everything works fine _without_ `submit()`, don't you think you should include the code for it so we can help define why it doesn't work with `submit()`? @SactoJosh Since OP was using jQuery I figured it would be best to use jQuery for event handling along with a few other minor improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the other comments here, it sounds like you want to show the GIF *AND* submit the form at the same time. You should do that like this:

```
<form onsubmit="addLoadingLayer()">
  <select name="selectItem" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <select name="selectItem2" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</form>

....
```

This combines the two. Any time one of your selects is changed, it submits the form and when the form is submitted, it calls your function.

Or you can assign the onchange to any select elements with jquery:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
  this.form.submit()
});
```

If this still doesn't work, we need to see more of your html / submit code to see what could be blocking it.